# create subtracted dataframe using multiple values from the bottom rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

**I have an example `df1` below...I need to create a new `df_sub` by subtracting values at the bottom of each column from the rest of the column.**

df_sub = i(every value in each column) - (a_squared * Temp + b * Temp + c)**

Example `df1.head()`

```
Temperature    A1     A2      A3      A4
  25.0      681.51  147.40  409.26  680.83
  25.2      615.89  124.34  362.39  618.37
  25.4      568.72   95.22  310.37  567.22
  25.6      522.08   89.74  272.69  516.53
  25.8      480.04   68.20  229.03  477.30
```

Example `df1.tail()`

```
Temperature    A1     A2       A3        A4
  95.0     -102.14  6348.77  2276.56  -2545.60
    a        15.26    10.67    -1.87     13.25  
    b     -1016.94  -623.29    29.40   -902.77
    c     16557.63  9044.62   715.07  14941.87
a_squared   232.95   113.95     3.53    175.65
```

**This is what I had tried, and the error I get...**

```
df_sub = df1.iloc[:-4] - (Temp * df1.iloc[-1, :] + (Temp * df1.iloc[-3, :]) + df1.iloc[-2, :])
```

Temp is a list like: `np.arange(25, 95.2, 0.2)`

*ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (96,) (351,)*

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What A1 to A4 columns mean? Are these measurements? Is this a physical phenomenon you are modeling?

Comment: @heltonbiker They are measurements from a temperature heating experiment...there are more columns and rows in reality.

Comment: So the first item of your problem seems weird. If you want to calculate `np.polyfit(x, y, 2)`, you need `x` values and `y` values. But you mention "rows 0, 1, 2 for each column", which would give three sequences, not two. So where would `x` come from, and where would `y` come from?

Comment: Any thoughts now @heltonbiker?

Comment: Sorry, I still find this confusing. Specifically, the idea of applying a different reggression for _each temperature value_ doesn't seem to make sense. Supposing you get this working, how do you expect to _use_ the found formulas? To extrapolate temperature values? Or extrapolate sensor readings given a temperature value? I think it would be much easier to analyze your difficulties with a better understanding of that.

Comment: What is `Temp` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `Temp` is some scalar is necessary create index by `Temperature` column by [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) as first step:

```
df1 = df1.set_index('Temperature')
print (df1)
                   A1       A2       A3        A4
Temperature                                      
25.0           681.51   147.40   409.26    680.83
25.2           615.89   124.34   362.39    618.37
25.4           568.72    95.22   310.37    567.22
25.6           522.08    89.74   272.69    516.53
25.8           480.04    68.20   229.03    477.30
95.0          -102.14  6348.77  2276.56  -2545.60
a               15.26    10.67    -1.87     13.25
b            -1016.94  -623.29    29.40   -902.77
c            16557.63  9044.62   715.07  14941.87
a_squared      232.95   113.95     3.53    175.65
```

And then multiple index values converted to numpy array with [broadcasting](http://scipy.github.io/old-wiki/pages/EricsBroadcastingDoc):

```
idx = df1.index
#if necessary convert index to numeric
#idx = pd.to_numeric(df1.index, errors='coerce')
a = df1.iloc[-1].values * idx[:-4].values[:, None]
b = df1.iloc[-3].values * idx[:-4].values[:, None]
df_sub = df1.iloc[:-4] - (a + b + df1.iloc[-2].values)
print (df_sub)
                    A1         A2        A3         A4
Temperature                                           
25.0          3723.630   3836.280 -1129.060   3916.960
25.2          3814.808   3915.088 -1182.516   3999.924
25.4          3924.436   3987.836 -1241.122   4094.198
25.6          4034.594   4084.224 -1285.388   4188.932
25.8          4149.352   4164.552 -1335.634   4295.126
95.0         57819.280  45691.450 -1566.860  51588.930
```

Comment: Temp is the Temperature column (index) not a scalar, I just wanted to show it goes from 25-95 in 0.2 steps. So there are 351 rows.

Comment: @Schnick - Please check solution now.

Comment: Just drop the '-4' from both instances of `idx[:-4].values[:, None]  Thanks!